# do (everywhere) continuity and linear directional derivatives imply differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be an *everywhere continuous* function and suppose there exists a linear map $L:  \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(tv)-f(0)}{t}= L(v)$$ for every unit vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Is f differentiable at 0?

This is motivated by a proof of the fact that, for a Lie group G, $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$ implies that $f$ is a smooth vector for the regular representation of $G$ on $L^2(G)$.  The author claims that it suffices to show the directional derivatives at $e\in G$ are given by the differential $X \mapsto Xf$, where $X\in \frak{g}$ is thought of as a differential operator.

Comment: why the downvote? I'm pretty sure this isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1119873/27978. This is the difference between a Gateaux and a Frechet derivative.

Comment: @copper.hat interesting. thanks