# Reformulating Real Analysis using any basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, change-of-basis

To illustrate the question that I'm asking, consider the theorem:

> If the partial derivatives of the $f$ exists in a neighbourhood of $c$
>   and are continuous at $c$, then $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

However, when we talk about partial derivatives, we talk about the directional derivative in the direction of the standard basis vectors (0,...,1,...0)of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

First of all, why do we choose and formulate the theorems with respect to these basis ? I mean would any orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$ work in the same way ?

I mean, for example, if we think geometrically, for $\mathbb{R}^3 $the choice of $x,y,z$ coordinates is arbitrary, hence any orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ should work, but how about *any* basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$
?

Secondly, if we were to formulate, for example, the above theorem wrt any basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$, how could we do that ?

**Edit:**

Please provide an argument to your statements.

**Edit 2:**

In the book that I'm using (*The elements of Real Analysis* by Bartle), for example, the above theorem is given before stating that the derivative of $f$ can be written in terms of the gradient, so to answer to this question, I cannot use this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis you chose to work with does matter. Indeed, consider a basis $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Rewriting the Fréchet derivative, for any $h=\sum_{k=1}^n h_i v_i$,

$$df(x)(h)=df(x)(\sum_{k=1}^n h_iv_i)=\sum_{k=1}^n h_i df(x)(v_i)$$

If you define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)$ as $df(x)(v_i)$ then you get the formula $df(x)(h) = \sum_{k=1}^n h_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)$.

However, you may not write this last quantity as $\nabla f(x)^Th$ because the $h_i$ are not necessarily the coordinates of $h$ in the canonical basis.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>First, your quoted theorem</strike>

> If the partial derivatives of the $f$ exists in a neighbourhood of $c$
>   and are continuous at $c$, then $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

May or may not actually be true depending on how you define differentiable. If your are referring to [Gâteaux differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative) then you are correct, but surprisingly not if you mean [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119873/gateaux-but-not-frechet-differentiable-functional) for a counterexample.

Your question actually touches on something very subtle. Consider the Jacobian of the function $f$--that is, the $p \times p$ matrix $J$ (in the standard basis), defined by

$$
J_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}.
$$

Where $f_i$ is the $i$th component of $f$ and $x_j$ the $j$th coordinate in the standard basis. Suppose now we transform from the standard basis to a new basis by the transformation $T : (x_j) \mapsto (x_j')$. We now have a new function

$$
\tilde{f} = T\circ f\circ T^{-1}.
$$

(That is $\tilde{f}$ first takes the vector in the new coordinates and converts back to the old, applies $f$, and then converts back to the new coordinates.) Using the chain rule, it can readily be deduced that the new Jacobian $J'$ is related to the old by

$$
J' = PJP^{-1},
$$

where $P$ is the change of basis matrix of the transformation $T$. Thus, we are free to work in whichever coordinates we may like, and may readily convert to a different set of linear coordinates by applying the standard change of basis matrix from linear algebra. We are thus at liberty to take the standard basis because, as this argument shows, all the other partial derivatives in any other linear coordinate system exist and are given by a change of basis with respect to the standard coordinates.

---

**Addendum:** This reasoning also explains a certain puzzle: when we encounter a vector function $\mathbf{u} : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ in physics, there are nine derivatives $\partial u_i/\partial x_j$ for $i,j = 1,2,3$. Why then do we only ever encounter two particular expressions $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}$ and $\nabla \times \mathbf{u}$ in our physics books?

It is because these combinations of partial derivatives are (in some sense) the only "derivatives" invariant under orthogonal transformations (and $\nabla \times \mathbf{u}$ is only "kind of" invariant under coordinate transformations, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector).)

We can see that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}$ is invariant under coordinate transformations since it is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) of the Jacobian, and the trace of a matrix is invariant with respect to change of basis.

Comment: The cited post gives an example of Gateaux differentiablility at a single point but not  Frechet differentiability at that point.  This is a far cry from what is being discussed here, where the partial derivatives exist everywhere and are continuous functions.  This is discussed in W. Flemming's *Functions of Several Variables*, section 2.3, for instance.  The stated result is proved, by use of the mean value theorem; the argument is too long to put in this post-it note.

Comment: @kimchilover I was mistaken. Edited

Comment: This was a very good answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your detailed answer. Secondly, how can we find P from T ? Thirdly, (just to be clear) when we talk about **partial derivative** of a function $f$, we always talk about the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction the standard basis right ? I mean if the function is in the form of $f(u, v)$ ,where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$, the partial derivative would still be $\partial f / \partial x$, where $x$ denotes the first element in the standard basis.

Comment: Edit: * the first partial derivative would still..

Comment: $P$ is constructed such that the $i$th column of $P$ is the coordinates of the first basis vector in the new coordinates. That is, $P_{ij} = T(x_j)_i$. (Double check me on this. It's very easy to get this messed up.)

Comment: By partial derivatives in this answer, I mean directional derivatives in the directions of the basis vectors in the standard basis (or the new basis when I refer to $\tilde f$.) As you highlight, the notation of a partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x$ is ill-defined unless you make it clear which degrees of freedom are "held constant" (i.e. choosing a basis).

Comment: In some problems, a natural basis will exist, but very often (particularly when multiple coordinate systems our present) the "first partial derivative" will be ambiguous, and you should clearly specify exactly what you are referring to. That said, in the absense of any clarification to the contrary, I would take the "first partial derivative" to mean "the direction derivative in the direction of the first element of the standard basis."

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $U$ be the matrix whose $i$-th column is $v_i$.
Notice that $U$ is orthogonal.
Let $g=f\circ U$.
Then

\begin{align}
g_i(x)
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{g(x+t\,e_i)-g(x)}t\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(U(x+t\,e_i))-f(Ux)}t\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(Ux+tUe_i))-f(Ux)}t=f_{v_i}(Ux)
\end{align}
In particular, $f_{v_i}(x)=g_i(U^Tx)$.
Do you think you can take it from here?

---

Notice that we used $U^T$ in the last step, but only because $U$ is orthogonal. The same argument works fine provided $U$ is invertible, that is, provided $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis.

Comment: Did you compose a matrix with a function ?

Comment: Yes. The function takes a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $U$ also does (for matrix multiplication).

Answer (score -2):

Any basis would suffice for this theorem.
We just use the standard basis because its the easiest to work with.

The best way to look at this is given that the theorem holds for a basis $v_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $e_j = \sum a_{i,j}v_i$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \sum a_{i,j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer ?  I mean claiming something without giving any reference/proof for that claim is almost meaningless.

Comment: @onurcanbektas directional derivatives are given by dotting with the gradient, the result follows from that.

Comment: @NoahRiggenbach I'm still not be able to see the result ? I mean most of the books differentiate the terms "partial derivative" and "directional derivate", so I would appreciate if you could provide a rigorous proof.

Comment: Plus, the fact that the derivative of $f$ at a point can be written in terms of the gradient is derived from the **partial derivatives**, so I cannot use it backwards.

Comment: I know that the derivative of a function is linear map (if it exists, of course), but how can you prove that the directional derivatives are also linear ?

Comment: sry i can't quite follow your question. Normally you prove this the same way you would prove it in the 1D case